# What CSS selector can be used to select the first div within another div

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have something like:

```
<div id="content>

   <h1>Welcome to Motor City Deli!</h1>
   <div style=" font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: bolder;">Sep 19, 2010</div>
   <div > ... </div>
```

What is the css selector for the second div (1st div within the "content" div) such that I can set the font color of the date within that div?

Comment: Please go accept the top voted answer, it's definitely correct.

Answer (score 307):

The MOST CORRECT answer to your question is...

```
#content > div:first-of-type { /* css */ }
```

This will apply the CSS to the first div that is a direct child of #content (which may or may not be the first child element of #content)

Another option:

```
#content > div:nth-of-type(1) { /* css */ }
```

Comment: Agree that it's the ONLY correct answer to the question and it should be accepted.

Comment: Can you tell me how to select all div `except` first/last div?

Comment: @HappyCoding  `#content > div:not(:last-of-type) { /* css */ }`

Comment: @Tân if you want all divs except the first AND last, it would be ...  `#content > div:not(:first-of-type):not(:last-of-type) { /* css */ }`

Answer (score 26):

You want

```
#content div:first-child {
/*css*/
}
```

Comment: Won't work because `<div>` is not the first child (it's `<h1>`).

Comment: Not to mention it won't work at all in IE even if the date `div` would be the first child.

Comment: Really? W3 says it will as long as a doctype is specified. (I honestly don't know though.)

Comment: Just ran a test, indeed it works if doctype is specified. In my defence, I wouldn't be surprised if stuff started working in IE if you'd type <the_cake_is_a_lie> at the top of the file ...

Comment: I always test before posting an answer. And the cake is a lie.

Comment: @Capt Otis: .. and the poor cube had to die for it :) But it doesn't change the fact that it still wouldn't work, with `h1` being the first child. Didn't test *that*, did you now ?

Comment: Haha obviously not. I would honestly use jQuery for this.

Comment: Does not work! Seems like the obvious answer, but the fact that this doesn't work is probably the reason for the question. Please remove.

Answer (score 16):

If we can assume that the H1 is always going to be there, then

```
div h1+div {...}
```

but don't be afraid to specify the id of the content div:

```
#content h1+div {...}
```

That's about as good as you can get cross-browser right now without resorting to a JavaScript library like jQuery. Using h1+div ensures that only the first div after the H1 gets the style. There are alternatives, but they rely on CSS3 selectors, and thus won't work on most IE installs.

Comment: +1. Didn't even think about that. Keep in mind this solution won't work in IE6.

Answer (score 5):

The closest thing to what you're looking for is the [:first-child pseudoclass](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pseudo_first-child.asp); unfortunately this will not work in your case because you have an `<h1>` before the `<div>s`. What I would suggest is that you either add a class to the `<div>`, like `<div class="first">` and then style it that way, or use jQuery if you really can't add a class:

`$('#content > div.first')`

Comment: misspell - should be `$('#content > div.first)`