# jQuery .append() only on first element

Tags: jquery, html, css, append

```
<div class="append-something first"></div>
<div class="append-something second"></div>
<div class="append-something third"></div>

$("#trigger").click(function() {
 $(".append-something").append("Some Stuff");
});
```

Hi there,
i want the above code to paste/append the words "Some Stuff" into the div-class "append-something" but only into the first div with the class-name. (In my code the words should append to "first", not to "second" or "third"). Thanks a lot!

Comment: `$(".append-something:first()").append("Some Stuff");` or `$(".append-something").first().append("Some Stuff");`

Comment: [And look this link for first div element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747547/what-css-selector-can-be-used-to-select-the-first-div-within-another-div)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `:first` or the `:first-child` selector. For only the last you should use the `:last` selector.

For any other element you can use the index of the element. jQuery will create an array of all the elements he finds with `append-something` class. So the first element will be index of `0`.

```
$("#trigger-first").click(function() {
// ":first" and ":first-child" will work.
    $(".append-something:first").append("Some Stuff");
});

$("#trigger-last").click(function() {
// ":last" for last option.
    $(".append-something:last").append("Some Stuff");
});

$("#trigger-second").click(function() {
// It will return an array of item so you can request on index.
    $($(".append-something")[1]).append("Some Stuff");
});
```

To play with it: https://jsfiddle.net/9bfskesb/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [first selector](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/):

```
 $(".append-something:first").append("Some Stuff");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  `$(".append-something:first").append("Some Stuff");` or if you have the class `.first` then simply   `$(".append-something.first").append("Some Stuff");`

```js
$("#trigger").click(function() {
 $(".append-something.first").append("Some Stuff");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="append-something first"></div>
<div class="append-something second"></div>
<div class="append-something third"></div>

<button id="trigger">click</button>
```

```js
$("#trigger").click(function() {
     $(".append-something:first").append("Some Stuff");
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="append-something first"></div>
<div class="append-something second"></div>
<div class="append-something third"></div>

<button id="trigger">click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You Can use prependTo() method
```

```js
$("<span>Hello World!</span>").prependTo(".inner:first-child");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:first` selector for this

```js
$("#trigger").click(function() {
 $(".append-something:first").append("Some Stuff");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="append-something"></div>
<div class="append-something"></div>
<div class="append-something"></div>

<button id="trigger">click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have already three different classes for each div i.e `first`, `second`, `third`. You can use the classes specifically to append the html as

```
 $(".first").append("Some Stuff");
```

But if you want to add using the same class for each div the you should go with

```
 $(".append-something:first").append("Some Stuff");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".append-something").first().append("Some Stuff");
```